# Can you pass an array of structs from WPF to hlsl pixel shader?

Tags: wpf, directx, hlsl

I am writing an WPF application which draws `n` points on surface. I want to pass each point's value into my hlsl pixel shader to do interpolation between them. Is there a way to pass an array of values into hlsl pixel shader? For example:

`float[] points : register(c0);`

and then in WPF:

```
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(Points),
                typeof(double[]),
                typeof(PixelShaderEffect),
                new PropertyMetadata(new double[1], PixelShaderConstantCallback(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hlsl does not accept array of floats as parameters from WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your array as 1D-texture. And one more argument - length of that array, so you can split your "texture" back to original values

UPD: some sample code. I'm not 100% sure it is correct way, unfortunately, I can't find my own code on this. But I remember I made it work, so I'm like 95% sure.

HLSL declarations:

```
uniform sampler1D MyArray: register(s0); 
uniform float ArrayLength:register(c0);    
float4 main(in float2 coord:TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float ArrayElement=tex1D(MyArray,0); // 2nd argument is actually number of element you need normalized to 0.0-1.0 range. So your value will be IndexOfElement/ArrayLength
//your HLSL code goes here
}
```

C# code. Suggesting you have shader class MyShader derived from ShaderEffect

```
class MyShader:ShaderEffect
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty 
MyArrayProperty=RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty("MyArray", typeof(MyShader ), 0);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ArrayLengthProperty=DependencyProperty.Register("ArrayLength", typeof(double), typeof(MyShader ), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, PixelShaderConstantCallback(0)));
    //your other properties and code
}
```

How to pass an array - this is my code which you need to slightly modify. You don't need gradients, you need image with size of ArrayLength x 1 with points colors made of your values.

```
SetValue(MyArrayProperty, new ImageBrush(new DrawingImage(new GeometryDrawing(new LinearGradientBrush(value), null, new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, ushort.MaxValue+1, 1))))));
```

Comment: can you write down an example of that? If what you say is true then this would be a huge improvement to how I did that so far!